# Flutter add Done button to keyboard in particular CupertinoTextField

Tags: flutter

I need to add Done button in Russian("Готово") up to text keyboard which appears after user wants to fill particular CupertinoTextField in app.
The way how it should look:
[Done button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bdmC6.jpg)
This text field has a dynamic size which width grows after user types multi-line text in it. How can I do that in Flutter? The code of widget with the textfield:

```
    @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    ProductEditBloc bloc = BlocProvider.of(context);
    return  SingleChildScrollView(
          child: CupertinoTextField(
            focusNode: focusNode,
            maxLines: null,
            onChanged: this.widget.onChanged,
            controller: this.widget.controller,
            keyboardType: TextInputType.multiline,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(border: null),
            textCapitalization: TextCapitalization.sentences,
            placeholder: bloc.productComment == null || bloc.productComment.isEmpty
                ? "Добавить заметку"
                : bloc.productComment,
            placeholderStyle: TextStyle(
                color: DesignColors.GREY_CHROME,
                fontSize: DesignFonts.FONT_SIZE__14,
                fontFamily: DesignFonts.FONT_FAMILY__REGULAR),
            style: TextStyle(
                color: DesignColors.GREY_COAL,
                fontSize: DesignFonts.FONT_SIZE__14,
                fontFamily: DesignFonts.FONT_FAMILY__REGULAR),
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(
              left: DesignPadding.V10,
              top: DesignPadding.V14,
              bottom: DesignPadding.V20,
            ),
          ),
        );
  }
```

Answer (score 7):

just add this line:

```dart
textInputAction: TextInputAction.done,
```

Comment: I tried this approach, but it is not suitable solution for me, I need to add done button in Russian above text keyboard like on image.